# Angular: OnPush ChangeDetectionStrategy benefit for components with only primitive values

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

Are there any performance benefits if a component has just primitive value bindings but uses ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush? Or are there probably some drawbacks in this situation?

Example use case:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() count: number;
}
```

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Because other change detector triggers (for example, any DOM events in the component) will not be fired with ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush